# Range of $f:\triangle\to \mathbb{R}$ where $\triangle$ is given triangle and $f(x,y)=|10x-3y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Consider the triangle with vertices $(1,2)$, $(-5,-1)$ and $(3,-2)$. Let $\triangle$ denote the region enclosed by the above triangle. Consider the function $f:\triangle\to \mathbb{R}$ denoted by $f(x,y)=|10x-3y|$. Then the range of $f$ is the interval $$(a)~[0,36];\quad(b)~[0,47];\quad(c)~[4,47];\quad(d)~[36,47];$$

I just draw the triangle and find $f(x,y)$ for arbitrarily values of $(x,y)$ in $\triangle$ and  try to discard one by one option. For example, the point $(0,0)$ is in  $\triangle$ and $f(0,0)=0.$ So the option $(c)$ and $(d)$ are not correct. But I'm stuck for option $(a)$ and $(b)$.

Is their any direct method and how can I ensure that the range is an interval without seeing the option.

Comment: Well, just look at the vertices.  $f(-5,-1)=47$.

Comment: Ok. good..So option $(b)$ is correct.  But any direct method or how can I show that $f$ assumes all the values from $0$ to $47$.

Comment: Well, some argument is needed, but I expect you can show that the max would have to be at a vertex.  To your question, look at the line between the two points you have found (the one yielding $0$ and the one yielding $47$).  By continuity, every value between $0,47$ is realized on that line.

Comment: To illustrate:  if $P$ is an interior point of the triangle then $P$ obviously can't be a max for $10x-3y$ (if, say $x≥0$ for $P$ then note that a ngbd of $P$ contains points with the same $y$ coord but greater $x$).